# If I accept a root Cert what am I opening myself up to?

Tags: certificates, wifi, man-in-the-middle

If I connect to a WIFI AP and it wants to install a root cert. They read my HTTPS traffic, Right?

Does using OpenSSH on my cell phone to my home router help protect me? Or can this traffic be decrypted as well?

Comment: *"... WIFI AP and it wants to install a root cert"* - how does the Wifi AP wants you to install a root certificate? Please explain this in more detail what happens here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich sounds like a capturing portal - maybe Russia with their new legislation?

Comment: BTW you don't Need to accept it, when the ssl certs are reissued for interception you can still manually decide to visit the site with unknown cert (at least if no HSTS is used, which somewhat makes HSTS contraproductive for those regions of the world)

Comment: @eckes: *"...maybe Russia with their new legislation?"* - or maybe the OP misinterpreting something. Unfortunately the question is lacking the details and the OP does not provide further information even when asked. This makes any assumptions what is actually happening here pure speculation.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yes was also thinking EAP/Radius cert but the op commented below "clearly root cert" (whatever that means :)

Comment: @eckes: *"(whatever that means :) "* - that's my point. Any assumptions here are totally based on the interpretation of the OP. It is unknown what this interpretation is based on and thus if it is even correct.

Answer (score 2):

> If I connect to a WIFI AP and it wants to install a root cert. They read my HTTPS traffic, Right?

Yes, they can read all of your HTTPS traffic including all of your passwords to any sites you log in to, all of your emails if you load your email, your credit card number if you buy something, etc. And it isn't read-only - it can tamper with them too, basically impersonating you to do anything they want, such as doing a bank transfer of your life's savings to their offshore account, if you log in to your bank.

> Does using OpenSSH on my cell phone to my home router help protect me? Or can this traffic be decrypted as well?

SSH doesn't need certificates, and the normal use case for it doesn't use them. It just compares keys directly, so a root CA won't compromise it. However, in practice, this won't be helpful, as any network that insists on a root CA will almost certainly not let you use SSH (or they may even try to MITM attack it too, but since the key would be different, you'd notice).

Note that accepting a certificate for a WPA-Enterprise connection is different than installing a root certificate for everything your device does. The former is safe and doesn't cause the above problems; only the latter is dangerous.

Comment: It was pretty clearly a root cert.